# How to allow user to practice alphabet on canvas in Android?

Tags: android, canvas

I am developing a application where I want, user can practice the English alphabets,clicking on "Practice" button.

I thought a logic that is, to create a activity that would display the alphabet, draw a transparent canvas on that and let user draw on top of that canvas seeing through transparent film over the activity. But I am new to android. So can anyone help me through reference or code please?